# “No Join Predicate” without alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables.
TableA:

[image]

TableB:

[image]

Also I have a function that returns a table value (1 and 3).

get_customer_id:

[image]

When running a query without alias, I get all the entries that satisfy the predicate of the inner join:

```
SELECT ID FROM TableA AS A
    INNER JOIN TableB AS B ON B.IDb = A.ID
WHERE EXISTS (select ID from get_customer_id() AS GCI WHERE GCI.ID = ID)
```

And the message "No Join Predicate" in the query plan. Although I expected to see only records with ID = 1 and 3.

I know that the problem can be solved in two ways.

1)

```
SELECT A.ID FROM TableA AS A
    INNER JOIN TableB AS B ON B.IDb = A.ID
WHERE EXISTS (select ID from get_customer_id() AS GCI WHERE GCI.ID = A.ID)
```

2)

```
SELECT ID FROM TableA AS A
    INNER JOIN TableB AS B ON B.IDb = A.ID
WHERE ID IN (select ID from get_customer_id())
```

But I can not understand why, if I do not specify alias, it does not return what I expected, it turns out that the condition does not hold? Why do I see a warning, only in terms of the query, why this problem does not fall into error?
*I will be grateful for any answers and references. I can not find an exact explanation on the Internet ...*

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35082/what-exactly-does-no-join-predicate-mean-in-sql-server. You should search before you post a question

Comment: @Sami, I got acquainted with this answer, but he did not bring clarity

Comment: Any reason you didn't just use two joins? And a distinct if you need to add it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You think that this subquery:

```
 WHERE EXISTS (select ID from get_customer_id() AS GCI WHERE GCI.ID = ID)
```

is interpreted as:

```
WHERE EXISTS (select ID from get_customer_id() AS GCI WHERE GCI.ID = A.ID)
```

That is wishful thinking.  The rules of scoping in SQL start with the closest `FROM`.  So this is really interpreted as:

```
WHERE EXISTS (select ID from get_customer_id() AS GCI WHERE GCI.ID = GCI.ID)
```

So, there is basically no "join predicate".

That is why you should *always* qualify column names.  By the way, you don't have to select `ID`, you can select anything.  I would typically write this as:

```
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from get_customer_id() gci gci.ID = a.ID)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I know that I can show a single in the sample and that is a good rule to give alias. But I just could not understand the condition, even though I looked at it in the query plan (`[Test].[dbo].[get_customer_id].[ID] as [GCI].[ID]=[Test].[dbo].[get_customer_id].[ID] as [GCI].[ID]`). But as usual the solution comes after the question :) Thanks again for your help.